# No binding res for object w/ thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Given:

- reactive chain with controller methods

  ```
  @PostMapping("/add")
  public Mono<String> addSkill(@ModelAttribute Skill skil) {
    log.info("skill "+ skill.getName() + " has been added!");
    return service.add(skill)
            .then(Mono.just(TEMPLATE));


  @GetMapping("")
  public Mono<String> getAll(Model model) {
    IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable driverContextVariable = new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(service.findAll(), 100);
    model.addAttribute("skills", driverContextVariable);
    return Mono.just(TEMPLATE);}
  ```
- form:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Reactive java skills</h1>
        </div>
        <table id="allSkills" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Skill Group</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="skills" data-th-each="skill : ${skills}">
                <td>[[${skill.name}]]</td>
                <td>[[${skill.level}]]</td>
                <td>[[${skill.priority}]]</td>
                <td>[[${skill.skillGroupName}]]</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div>
        <h4>add skill</h4>
        <form th:action="@{/skill/add}" th:object="${skill}" method="post">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{skill.name}" placeholder="choose skill name"/>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{skill.level}" placeholder="choose skill level"/>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{skill.priority}" placeholder="choose skill priority"/>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{skill.skillGroupName}" placeholder="choose skill priority"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

My goal is simple:to add a new entity by submitting form and render the same
html which shows all entities. As far as I understood concept of Reactive Thyme, here is no @PathVariable due to blocking code behind it, so I use @ModelAttribute to pass params for new Skill. However, when I request base path for the controller, it renders all the skills and throws :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'skill' available as request attribute

I have no glue how to make thymeleaf ignore `${skill}` param when I render the page and use it only on submitting form.

PS - I also haven't found official docs for reactive thymeleaf, if anyone shares link it would be awesome.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to note that besides the IllegalStateException, it renders getAll(Model model) entities, but does'mt render the form of input at all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I am supposed to fullfil all attributes in reactive way. So, the problem was with my getAll() method, which should be capable of filling all thymeleaf object claimed in template html. The working version of method I put for better memorizing reason:

```
@GetMapping("")
public Mono<String> getAll(Model model) {
    log.info("no attr =- no future");
    return Mono.just(model)
            .flatMap(m -> {
                m.addAttribute("skills", new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(service.findAll(), 10));
                m.addAttribute("skill", new Skill());
                return Mono.just(TEMPLATE);

            })
          .doOnNext(sink -> System.out.println(sink));
```